# form main + form child stacking issue

Tags: delphi

I am using main form and child forms.

If I open 2nd child form with

TMYForm.Create(nil);

It does not stack it on the 1st child form top.

Is there any way for 2nd and X'th child form to appear in exact same position as 1st child form?

Or I need to destroy old child form while creating new one (as stacking is done automatically)?

Comment: P.S. I have tried destroying child form just before using nil, but still stacks it in different location, although 1st child form is no longer visible.

Comment: Is this a modal or non-modal form? For modal you need to ensure that the z-order is correct, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. Without specifying otherwise, Forms will open on the right and down from the position of the previously opened.
If you want to control the position of your form, change its `Position` property to `poDesigned`, but you have to set its `Top` and `Left` properties to ensure it'll be visible.
Or you can used some presets: `poDesktopCenter, poMainFormCenter, poOwnerFormCenter` or `poScreenCenter`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this:

TMYForm.Position:=poMainFormCenter;

or

TMYForm.Position:=poOwnerFormCenter;

Before TMYForm.Create(nil);

-S

Answer (score 0):

If you have references to the child forms, use Form2.BoundsRect := Form1.BoundsRect